# React-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am making a blog app. Where if I try to access the individual profiles the spinner keeps running, but the data is there when I check in the react dev tools. Where did I go wrong? Everything else was working fine. The profiles are visible, but when I get inside the individual profile is where the problem happens

Profile.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import { getProfileById } from "../../actions/profile";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Profile = ({ getProfileById, profile: { profile }, auth, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileById(match.params.id);
  }, [getProfileById, match.params.id]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {profile === null ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <Link to='/profiles' className='btn btn-light'>
            Back to Profiles
          </Link>
          {auth.isAuthenticated &&
            auth.loading === false &&
            auth.user._id === profile.user._id && (
              <Link to='/edit-profile' className='btn btn-dark'>
                Edit Profile
              </Link>
            )}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Profile.propTypes = {
  getProfileById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProfileById })(Profile);
```

The source from which the data is comming, profile.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";

import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_ERROR,
  UPDATE_PROFILE,
  ACCOUNT_DELETED,
  CLEAR_PROFILE,
  GET_PROFILES,
  GET_REPOS,
} from "./types";

export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/profile/me");

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Get all profiles
export const getProfiles = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CLEAR_PROFILE });

  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/profile");

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILES,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Get Profile by id
export const getProfileById = (userId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/profile/user/${userId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILES,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Get github repos
export const getGithubRepos = (username) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/profile/github/${username}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_REPOS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Create or Update profile
export const createProfile =
  (formData, history, edit = false) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const res = await axios.post("/api/profile", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data,
      });

      dispatch(setAlert(edit ? "Profile Updated" : "Profile Created"));

      if (!edit) {
        history.push("/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const errors = error.response.data.errors;

      if (errors) {
        errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
      }

      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: {
          msg: error.response.statusText,
          status: error.response.status,
        },
      });
    }
  };

//Add experience
export const addExperience = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const res = await axios.put("/api/profile/experience", formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Experience Added", "success"));

    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    const errors = error.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Add Education
export const addEducation = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put("/api/profile/education", formData);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Education Added", "success"));

    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    const errors = error.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

// Delete experience
export const deleteExperience = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/profile/experience/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Experience Deleted", "success"));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

// Delete education
export const deleteEducation = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/profile/education/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Education Deleted", "success"));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Delete account & profile
export const deleteAccount = () => async (dispatch) => {
  if (
    window.confirm("Are you sure? This will be permanently delete the account!")
  )
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/profile`);

      dispatch({
        type: CLEAR_PROFILE,
      });
      dispatch({
        type: ACCOUNT_DELETED,
      });

      dispatch(setAlert("Account Removed"));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: {
          msg: error.response.statusText,
          status: error.response.status,
        },
      });
    }
};
```

[My github repo Link](https://github.com/Trungks82/blog-app)

Answer (score 0):

under src -> components -> profile.js

at the bottom you did define mapStateToProps, however you never created the function mapDispatch which is used to grab the data from your thunk call getProfileById

here is more info:
ctrl + find  -> mapDispatchToProps
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: [My reducer for profile.js.](https://github.com/Trungks82/blog-app/blob/master/client/src/reducers/profile.js)

Comment: What you said,I already did it at the begining. But the error still doesn't go away

Answer (score 0):

Your actions expect a dispatch function as the second function's parameter. But you aren't providing it anywhere.

Considering how your actions are written this should resolve the issue:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileById(match.params.id)(dispatch);
  }, [dispatch, getProfileById, match.params.id]);
```

Also, you are providing `getProfileById` as the component property and you have it as an import on top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It worked.
There was some error in the getProfilebyID function.

Comment: can you push the solution to your repo? I wanna see what fixed it

Comment: Its already in that link in the question. In the getProfilebyID, I used  one action `GET_PROFILES`  , where it should have been `GET_PROFILE`

Comment: i.e, in the dashboard I already got all the profiles by `GET_PROFILES` .I was again calling all the profiles to show itself when I wanted to view the individual profile with the `GET_PROFILES`. It should have been `GET_PROFILE`, which gives back the individual profiles details based on their 'id'.
I hope I am making sense